# Absolute div not at the specified position inside relative div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a calendar with events on it, here is my code snippet:

```css
div#planning {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#planning .heure {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: -0.9px 0 0 -0.9px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#planning>.jour {
  width: unset;
  max-width: unset;
}

#planning>.jour:before {
  content: attr(data-header);
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #919293;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#planning>.jour:first-child {
  margin-left: 24px;
}

.jour:first-child .heure:before {
  content: attr(data-header);
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -7px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  font-size: 12px;
}

.horaire {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #00adff;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.jour>div {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

#formhoraires .miniform input {
  width: 60px;
}

#collaborateur .miniform {
  width: unset;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

div#horaires {
  min-height: unset;
}
```

```html
<div id="planning" class="form vertical">
  <div class="jour" data-header="mer.01/03">
    <div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="7h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="8h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="9h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="10h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="11h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="12h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="13h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="14h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="15h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="16h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="17h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="18h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="19h"></div>
      <div class="heure" data-header="20h"></div>
      <div class="horaire" style="top:0px;height:140px"></div>
      <div class="horaire" style="top:420px;height:35px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jour" data-header="jeu.02/03">
    <div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="horaire" style="top:70px;height:140px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jour" data-header="ven.03/03">
    <div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="horaire" style="top:35px;height:140px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jour" data-header="sam.04/03">
    <div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jour" data-header="dim.05/03">
    <div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="horaire" style="top:35px;height:140px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jour" data-header="lun.06/03">
    <div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="horaire" style="top:0px;height:140px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jour" data-header="mar.07/03">
    <div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="heure"></div>
      <div class="horaire" style="top:35px;height:105px"></div>
      <div class="horaire" style="top:420px;height:35px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0sL1pufa/

As you can see the divs with the class `horaire` have an error offset when them are not at the top. I measured that the `.heure` divs have the exact specified height, but the `.horaire` divs are not at the specified y position.

As the `.heure` divs are 35 pixels, a `.horaire` div with a `top` value of `420px` should be exactly on the 12th row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are adding margin top to `#planning .heure`

```
#planning .heure {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: -0.9px 0 0 -0.9px; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< top is -0.9 so you are pushing contect from top to bottom
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```